# subnormal subgroup of a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I could not reason with this statement of a proof I am currently looking at.

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group with $Q\leq G$ and suppose that $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of $Q$ then $H$ is subnormal in $N_G(Q)$

I can't see how $H \unlhd Q$

Comment: Any subgroup of a finite $\;p\,-$ group is subnormal. This much is true for *any* nilpotent group, certainly. Are you sure of the conditions? Because I can't see how $\;H\;$ being cyclic is relevant here. Also, I can't understand why would we have $\;H\lhd Q\;$ ...? Please check the conditions and what you wrote.

Comment: what
happens if $G=Q$ and $\mid H\mid=p$,

Comment: @m.idaya I don't understand what you are asking. As Joanperno said the statement that $H$ is subnormal in $N_G(Q)$ is true because $N_G(Q)$ is a $p$-group. The rest of the information in the question is irrelevant. It is not true in general that $H \unlhd Q$, but that is also irrelevant to the question.

Comment: then by translating the text in my langauge I can't understand the question

Comment: can the author explain more what is the question

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you. I forgot that this is true for any nilpotent group and $G$ being a finite $p$-group is nilpotent.